# Schmidt group and Permute 2-maximal subgroup with 3-maximal subgroup

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

$G$ is Schmidt group With abelian Sylow subgroup Then every $2$-maximal subgroup of $G$ permuts with all $3$-maximal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why "hold" ? I neeed prove this sentence.

Comment: Please don't discriminate against foreigners, those who are voting to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $G$ is Schmidt group. $G=Q\ltimes P$.($P$ is p-Sylow subgroup and $Q$ is q-Sylow subgroup).

We know Maximal subgroups of Schmidt Group is  $\langle a \rangle \times P$ and $\lbrace P'\times Q^{x} |x\in G\rbrace$(i dont have any proof this).

I just Show  Every maximal and 2-maximal of $Q^{x}$ is normal in $G$. by [Schmidt group and sylow subgroup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/416765/schmidt-group-and-sylow-subgroup) Every maximal and 2-maximal of q-Sylow subgroup of $G$, is normal in $G$. Then every 2-maximal of $G$ permute with evrey 3-maximal of $G$. if 2-maximal and 3-maximal select in $\langle a \rangle \times P$. easy to see permute(because $\langle a \rangle \times P$ is abelian group)