# On the group with nilpotent maximal subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group such that every maximal subgroup of $G$ is nilpotent. Then why $G$ is solvable?

I know if $G$ is nilpotent then $G$ is solvable. So let $G$ is non-nilpotent. Thus there exists a maximal subgroup, say $M$, of $G$ which is non-normal in $G$.

Comment: This is a nontrivial result. I would advise looking it up in a textbook rather than trying to prove it yourself. Such groups are called Schmidt groups. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414937 for references for a proof.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the commutator subgroup $[G,G]$ it is contained in a maximal subgroup which is nilpotent, so it is also nilpotent. This is equivalent to saying that $G$ is solvable.

Comment: $G^{\prime}$ is nilpotent, then why $G$ is solvable?

Comment: It is a definition of solvable group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup#Classes_of_groups

Comment: Ok thats right, now if $G^{\prime}=G$, then what happen?